# Embedding MediaWiki Pages in Class Documentation

Tags: eclipse, documentation, javadoc, mediawiki

I would like to know if there is any possibility to embed mediawiki pages in the javadoc view in eclipse?

We maintain a wiki with informations related to our modules, some functionality, specific problems that were encountered and other stuff. I would like to bring this documentation closer to our codebase. Moving everything from the wiki to javadoc is not possible, because the wiki is also accessible to people, who do not access code and there is also a lack of support for images in javadoc.

I thought of something like displaying the wikipage that is named like the class, whos javadoc I am currently viewing or using special javadoc tags.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add Links in your JavaDoc to your wiki with html-code. You can use the links without the `@see` tag, so it is not listed at the bottom of your doc.

```
/**
 * @see <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> 
 */
```

you can open the links in the JavaDoc-View in Eclipse, so it will not ne opened in the source-view.

Comment: I thought about that too, but hoped to find a more elaborate solution. But since there is not much need for this, such a solution doesn't exist yet. So I'm going to accept this.